# Eigen support for s390x vectorization?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have tried simple example using eigen vector functions on both the platforms : Intel and s390x.
Reference: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization
On Intel , the code can compile with vectorization (by default -msse2 ) and generates output.

On s390x, compilation failed with an error: `__builtin_s390_vfi was not declared in this scope`.

Error: 
`In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:385:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from mypgm.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/ZVector/PacketMath.h: In function âPacket Eigen::internal::pmin(const Packet&, const Packet&) [with Packet = __vector(2) double]â:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/ZVector/PacketMath.h:567:115: error: â__builtin_s390_vec_minâ matching variant requires z14 or higher
 template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Packet2d pmin<Packet2d>(const Packet2d& a, const Packet2d& b) { return vec_min(a, b); }
                                                                                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:220:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from mypgm.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/ZVector/PacketMath.h: In function âPacket Eigen::internal::pround(const Packet&) [with Packet = Eigen::internal::Packet4f]â:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/ZVector/PacketMath.h:629:16: error: â__builtin_s390_vfiâ was not declared in this scope
   res.v4f[0] = vec_round(a.v4f[0]);`

Same issue is observed while building TensorFlow with vectorization on z14 vm.

I have used -march=z14 -mzvector flags on z14 s390x vm.

Is Eigen supports vectorization for s390x?

Comment: Is it the only error you get? What's your compiler version? Have you tried with the head of Eigen?

Comment: Tried simple example from here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/GettingStarted.html. 

command :  g++ my_program.cpp -I/usr/include/eigen3/ -march=z13 -mzvector -o my_program

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

installed eigen by apt-get install libeigen3-dev